# Dropdown List Not Working (copied template from Bootsnipp)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2017

I copied the template from https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/search-panel-with-filters and edited to meet my need such that it looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Member ID</a></li>
                </ul>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function (e) {
                        $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
                            var concept = $(this).text();
                            $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
                            $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search keyword">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I'm having some issues with the dropdown list. It does not drop upon clicking.

I have imported the necessary jQuery and Bootstrap files as follows:

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<li><a href="#less_than">Less than < </a></li>` you are having an additional `<` brace

Comment: Please use your html script in external js or at the end of your html body.

Answer (score 0):

You are having additional `<` and `>` symbols which should be replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```
<li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than &gt;</a></li>
<li><a href="#less_than">Less than &lt; </a></li>
```